# Run operation on all text nodes in a document which are not children of an element with a tagName in a list of tags

Tags: javascript

I have been trying different methods of doing this, however they are all quite slow.

noGlobalTags is an array containing three tags.

Method 1:

```
var textNodeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, function(node){return (noGlobalTags.indexOf(node.tagName)==-1)? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;}, false);
var cn;
while(cn = textNodeWalker.nextNode()){
  textNodeEmoteParser(cn);
}
return;
```

Method 2:

```
function getTextNodes(node) {
    if(node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodeEmoteParser(node);
    } else {
        for(var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if(noGlobalTags.indexOf(node.childNodes[i].tagName)!=-1) {
                continue;
            }
            getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}

getTextNodes(node);
```

I had expected method 1 to be the quickest, however it took double as long as the second method. Am I doing something stupid here? If not, can I make it faster than the second method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, inline code (as in the 2nd example), is nearly always faster than using callbacks (as in the 1st example).  Javascript has a meaningful amount of overhead for a function call.

So, the generic treeWalker method with callbacks isn't as likely to every be as fast as a direct coded method in your 2nd example.

One finds the same thing is true when comparing a `for` loop direct iteration of an array to a `.forEach()` iteration of the same array for the same reaons.  Callback functions are slow.

The code with callback functions can often be more generically useful and sometimes much shorter, but not necessarily faster to execute.

This shouldn't be surprising if you think about what's happening in javascript.  To call a function, it has to do a lookup of the name, then it has to create a new function context, pass the parameters to the function, create any local variables in that function, execute the code in that function, clean up all of the above when done, return from that function and continuing execution after the function call.  The inline code version skips a lot of these steps.

FYI, you can speed both of them up if you put the tags in an object instead of an array:

```
var noGlobalTags = {"LI": true, "UL": true};
```

Then, you can check if a given tag is in that list with this type of code:

```
noGlobalTags[node.tagName]                    // your first example
```

or

```
if (noGlobalTags[node.childNodes[i].tagName])   // your second example
```

which should be significantly faster than the array search you are currently using.

Here's a non-recursive version that also uses the faster noGlobalTags lookup:

```
function getTextNodes(top) {
    var queue = [], index, item, node;

    // put the first node into the work queue
    queue.unshift({nodes: [top], pos: 0});

    // keep going while more work to go
    while (queue.length) {
        item = queue[0];
        index = item.pos++;
        // if there are more items to go, process the next one
        if (index < item.nodes.length) {
            node = item.nodes[index];
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                // if it's a text node, call the parser
                textNodeEmoteParser(node);
            } else {
                // not a text node, get it's children
                // and put them at the start of the array 
                // to be processed next
                if (node.childNodes.length && !noGlobalTags[node.tagName]) {
                    queue.unshift({nodes: node.childNodes, pos: 0});
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no more of these children to process
            // remove them from the queue
            queue.shift();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: nearly 100x faster.  I found a different method that actually just walks the tree directly that is a lot faster:

```
function customIterativeTreeWalker(root) {
    var node = root.firstChild;
    while(node != null) {
        if(node.nodeType == 3) {
            textNodeEmoteParser(node);
        }
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            // if it has a tagName and the tabName is in our table
            // skip going into the tag
            if (node.tagName && noGlobalTags[node.tagName]) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
            } else {
                // go down into the children
                node = node.firstChild;
            }
        } else {
            while (node.nextSibling == null) {
                node = node.parentNode;
                if (node == root) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
```

JSPerf here: http://jsperf.com/get-text-nodes-non-recursive/3

Comment: Thanks! Before I try implementing it, is there any obvious reason that would make managing my own stack of nodes to eliminate the `getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);` function call slower than the function call?

Comment: Recursively calling `getTextNodes()` like you have is a lot simpler than not using recursion, but a non-recursive version could be faster (because it avoids the function call), but whether it actually is faster or not depends upon how you efficiently you handle the stack of nodes and nested loops.

Comment: Thanks! That was a lot faster than my first attempt - http://jsperf.com/get-text-nodes-non-recursive/

Comment: In case it matters, your non-recursive version `getTextNodesIn()` is simpler code, but as a consequence, doesn't process the nodes in document order (which I figured would be a requirement).  The speed difference between yours and mine must be because you are copying every `childNodes` array into your `tnStack` and I'm just referring to it in my `queue`.  My `queue` contains arrays of children and an iteration position within that queue, while your `tnStack` contains individual nodes.

Comment: I made a few further performance improvements in both my algorithm and yours here: http://jsperf.com/get-text-nodes-non-recursive/3.  Method 5 is an improvement on your technique by concantenating a copy of the whole childNodes array at once rather than looping through it.  My method improved slightly by using push/pop instead of shift/unshift.

Comment: @nallar - I found a method that is nearly 100x faster that doesn't deal with childNode arrays, but walks the tree directly using `firstChild`, `nextSibling` and `parentNode`.  I added this option to the end of my answer and added it into your jsperf.

Comment: Does the relatively terrible performance it had with Chrome 19 for me look like a bug? Should I report it?

Comment: @nallar - yeah, it sure looks like something is wrong with that in Chrome 19.  Still almost 50% faster than any other method, but not even close to what I got in Chrome 17.

Comment: @nallar - And Chrome 19 is slower than IE9 on this new algorithm which I think the Google folks would think was a bad thing.